# Solving a polynomial equation with a condition of equality on roots

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

Let the following equation have two equal roots:

```
f[x_] := x^3 - p x^2 + q x - r
```

And I want to find out what the three roots are. Not knowing how to put this condition within a Solve or Reduce, I have to rely on transcribing some algebra into MMA.
So if the above equation has  two equal roots, then

```
fr[x_] := 3 x^2 - 2 p x + q
```

has one of them, out of a theorem on the depression of equations.
If I put this into Solve this leads to:

```
Solve[x^3 - p x^2 + q  x - r == 0   && 3 x^2 - 2 p  x + q == 0, x]
```

No error message but MMA is unable to give here one the the duplicate solution.
So I put more algebra into the code:

```
PolynomialRemainder[f[x], fr[x], x]    (* the remainder must he equal to zero *)
rootduplicate = x /. Solve[% == 0, x]  (* gives the value of the two equal roots *)
```

The third root is within the third factor of f[x]:

```
PolynomialQuotient[f[x], (x - rootduplicate[[1]])^2, x] // FullSimplify
Solve[% == 0, x]
root3 = x /. {%}
```

Let's check it up with an example:

```
Solve[(x^3 - p x^2 + q  x - r /. {p -> 4, q -> 5, r -> 2}) ==  0   && (3 x^2 - 2 p  x + q /. {p -> 4, q -> 5}) == 0, x]    (* now MMA finds a double root *)
Solve[(x^3 - p x^2 + q  x - r /. {p -> 4, q -> 5, r -> 2}) ==  0   , x] 
rootduplicate /. {p -> 4, q -> 5, r -> 2}
root3 /. {p -> 4, q -> 5, r -> 2}
root3 == {(p - 2 rootduplicate)} // FullSimplify (* another verification out of algebra   - is there a way with MMA to find out this relation without hardcoding it? *)
```

My questions:

- Why MMA (V8) is unable to find a solution in my first Solve ?
- Is there a better way relying less on algebra to get these solutions?

Comment: What specifically are you looking to obtain for a solution? Possibly `SolveAlways[x^3 - p x^2 + q x - r == (x - r1)^2*(x - r2), x]` is along the lines of what you want?

Comment: I want  an expression  for  r1 and r2  which involves only p, q, 
r. You suggest an expression for p, q, r which involves r1 and r2. That's different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that if your polynomial has two identical roots then :
$$x^3 - p x^2 + q x - r == (x - xs)^2 (x - xd)$$

and you can solve for the unknowns `xs, xs` in terms of the other parameters.

```
sol = Reduce[
       Thread[
        CoefficientList[(x - xs)^2 (x - xd) - (x^3 - p x^2 + q x - r), x] == 0]
      , {xs, xd}] ;
```

Check :

```
example = {p -> 4, q -> 5, r -> 2} ;

sol //. example
(* xs == 1 && xd == 4 - 2 xs *)

Solve[(x^3 - p x^2 + q x - r /. example) == 0, x]
(* {{x -> 1}, {x -> 1}, {x -> 2}} *)
```

Comment: Ingenious! I wonder why MMA in the ConditionalExpression list  xd is always expressed as `xd == p - 2 xs` (which is correct) and not an expression involving only p,q,r (root3 in my question)

Comment: `xd` in your solution is the simple root, `xs` the double root

Comment: You can use `Solve[sol /. example]` to get an explicit solution for `xs, xd`.

Comment: @SigismondKmiecik Yes, "d" for different and "s" for same.

Answer (score 3):

I would approach the problem like this:

```
f[x_] := x^3 - p x^2 + q x - r
```

Now try

```
Solve[{f[x]==0, f'[x]==0}, x]
```

which returns `{}` meaning that there are no solutions.  More specifically it means that there are no solutions for *arbitrary* `p`, `q` and `r`, but there *might be* solutions if these parameters satisfy certain conditions.  We can ask *Mathematica* to generate those conditions:

```
Solve[{f[x] == 0, f'[x] == 0}, x, MaxExtraConditions -> Infinity]

{{x -> ConditionalExpression[p/3, p^2 - 3 q == 0 && p^3 - 27 r == 0]}, 
 {x -> ConditionalExpression[p/3, p^2 - 3 q == 0 && p^3 - 27 r == 0]}, 
 {x -> ConditionalExpression[(p q - 9 r)/(2 (p^2 - 3 q)), -p^2 q^2 + 4 q^3 + 4 p^3 r - 18 p q r + 27 r^2 == 0]}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Equating coefficients makes sense: the polynomial `x^3 - p x^2 + q x - r` must be equal to

```
Expand[(x - a)^2 (x - b)]
-a^2 b + a^2 x + 2 a b x - 2 a x^2 - b x^2 + x^3
```

Hence

```
p == b + 2 a
q == a^2 + 2 a b
r == a^2 b
```

Applying `Solve` gives several possible answers in the form of `ConditionalExpressions`.

```
Solve[p == b + 2 a && q == a^2 + 2 a b && r == a^2 b, {a, b}, 
      MaxExtraConditions -> Infinity]
```

If all you need is a single numerical example:

```
  FindInstance[p == b + 2 a && q == a^2 + 2 a b && r == a^2 b, 
       {a, b, p, q, r}, Reals]

 {{a -> 33/10, b -> 8/5, p -> 41/5, q -> 429/20, r -> 2178/125}}
```

If you want more answers, you can ask `FindInstance` for more, as noted by Sigismond. If you want answers with specific values, you can do it manually. For instance, to find three answer sets where p=5

```
FindInstance[5 == b + 2 a && q == a^2 + 2 a b && r == a^2 b, 
    {a, b, q, r}, Reals, 3]
```

Comment: I like your answer as it is easy with it to find n different instances just by adding ,n at the end of your FindInstance. Is it possible to get an instance by replacing any of the p,q,r parametres by a numerical value? I tried `FindInstance[
  p == b + 2 a && q == a^2 + 2 a b && r == -a^2 b, {a, b, p, q, r}, 
  Reals] /. {p -> 5}
` but this does not work

Comment: The update shows one way of getting specific answers.

Comment: Try `Solve[(x^3 - p x^2 + q x - r /. {p -> 41/5, q -> 429/20, 
     r -> -2178/125}) == 0, x]  (* your solution *)
Solve[(x^3 - p x^2 + q x - r /. {p -> 41/5, q -> 429/20, 
     r -> 2178/125}) == 0, x] (* r sign changed*) ` Updated prompted by @DanielLichtBlau  answer.

Comment: I had switched the sign on `r`, it's now switched back.

Answer (score 3):

Could do

```
Solve[{x^3 - p x^2 + q x - r == 0, r1 + r2 + r3 == p, r1 == r2, 
  r1*r2 + r1*r3 + r2*r3 == q, r1*r2*r3 == r}, {r1, r2, r3}, {x, p}]
```

The requirement of a double root places a relation on {p,q,r}, so I chose to eliminate `p`. An alternative is to solve for one of them e.g. `p`, or to do

```
Solve[{x^3 - p x^2 + q x - r == 0, r1 + r2 + r3 == p, r1 == r2, 
  r1*r2 + r1*r3 + r2*r3 == q, r1*r2*r3 == r}, {r1, r2, r3}, {x}, 
 MaxExtraConditions -> 1]

(* {{r1 -> ConditionalExpression[(p q - 9 r)/(
    2 (p^2 - 3 q)), -p^2 q^2 + 4 q^3 + 4 p^3 r - 18 p q r + 27 r^2 == 
     0], r2 -> 
   ConditionalExpression[(p q - 9 r)/(
    2 (p^2 - 3 q)), -p^2 q^2 + 4 q^3 + 4 p^3 r - 18 p q r + 27 r^2 == 
     0], r3 -> 
   ConditionalExpression[(p^3 - 4 p q + 9 r)/(
    p^2 - 3 q), -p^2 q^2 + 4 q^3 + 4 p^3 r - 18 p q r + 27 r^2 == 0]}} *)
```

Comment: I'm impressed. How did you find out the relations `r1*r2 + r1*r3 + r2*r3 == q, r1*r2*r3 == r` - It's not a MMA question but an algebra question.

Comment: @Sigismond Kmiecik Just expand `(x-r1)*(x-r2)*(x-r3)`, then equate coefficients in powers of `x` to those of `x^3-p*x^2+q*x-r`.

Comment: Indeed! Easier with MMA than with algebra demonstrations! Thanks